# Google Actions - how to add testers before final deployment

Tags: actions-on-google

someone knows how to add testers to an action on google package?
So other users can test the implementation on their Google Home devices?

Thanks!

Comment: Other testers are not supported yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today you must use the developer's account to test except for the case of account linking where testers can put their own credentials in for that specific step, and test any functionality that relies on that. I am told by the Actions on Google support team that providing a mechanism for testers (with different accounts than the developer) to access Actions/agents prior to deployment is the number 1 requested feature "by far" so hopefully we will see it down the road.

Comment: Any update on this since April, considering it's a #1 request?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Make sure everything under "Directory information" is filled out. Then go to the "Release" tab under "Deploy", and click on Alpha (which allows a quicker deploy for up to 20 users without review). Click "Submit for Alpha", and ensure you meet the requirements to check the checkboxes there. After that, you can press "Manage alpha testers" under the Alpha pane, where you can generate a link or add email addresses.

(screenshots anyone?)